# how to solve these ALSA errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, alsa, libalsa

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listener= sr.Recognizer()
try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("hai say something...")
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(command)
except:
    pass
```

This is my code. when i try to run this it shows the following error

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:641:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
hai say something...
```

I'm using conda env.i already searched a lot about ALSA errors but only jackd2 error was solved. please help me to solve this error.

Comment: i can see that the modules are working . because when i write this comment python -m speech_recognition     in the terminal. the demo code is working. the errors is still there but its recegonise what i said

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem ? I have the same issue on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: @16ar, I didn't solve it. I didn't get a solution for this issue.

Answer (score -1):

On Debian OS, this command solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).